# MVC3 controlling FilePath in fileupload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I need help to make fileupload.cs reusable for uploading gallery images in content/gallery folder and downloadable files  in  content/files folder. I believe the solution will be in making the  filepaths string somehow dynamic. The gallery and  File have different controllers,models and views.  Below is the fileupload.cs code

```
public static class FileUpload

{
    public static char DirSeparator =  System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    public static string FilesPath = "Content" + DirSeparator + "Files" + DirSeparator;
    public static string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Check if we have a file
        if (null == file) return "";
        // Make sure the file has content
        if (!(file.ContentLength > 0)) return "";
        string fileName = file.FileName;
        string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        // Make sure we were able to determine a proper 
        // extension
        if (null == fileExt) return "";
        // Check if the directory we are saving to exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+FilesPath))
        {
        // If it doesn't exist, create the directory
            Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+FilesPath);
        }
        // Set our full path for saving
        string path = FilesPath + DirSeparator + fileName;
        // Save our file
        //file.SaveAs(Path.GetFullPath(path));
        file.SaveAs(Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +path));
        // Return the filename
        return fileName;
    }
    public static void DeleteFile(string fileName)
    {
    // Don't do anything if there is no name
        if (fileName.Length == 0) return;
   // Set our full path for deleting
        string path = FilesPath + DirSeparator + fileName;
     // Check if our file exists
        if (File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+path)))
        {
            // Delete our file
            File.Delete(Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+path));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work? Showing some source code that you found somewhere on the internet which meets your requirements at 90% and asking for someone else to do the other 10% is not what Stack Overflow was meant for. You are saying that you are believing that `the solution will be in making the filepaths string somehow dynamic`, which is great. How more precisely did you try to materliaze this initial idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if uploaded file has konwn image format extension (jpg, gif, png, etc) and if so then save to your content/gallery folder otherwise save to your content/files folder.

You are checking the file etension anyway

```
string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
```

but you never use it.